# How to apply querySelectorAll() on NodeList[]?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

```
for(var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {

 var inputs = mutation.addedNodes[i];

 console.log(inputs);

}
```

I want to apply querySelectorAll() on inputs but it is throwing an error

> Uncaught TypeError: mutation.addedNodes[i].querySelectorAll is not a function.

Comment: Just check if the `mutation.addedNodes[i]` is not a text node. Also share a working snippet using `<>` that replicates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it is throwing an error **Uncaught TypeError:
>   mutation.addedNodes[i].querySelectorAll** is not a function.

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) is invoked on an `Element` (doesn't include TextNode), just check if `mutation.addedNodes[i]` is an `Element` or not.

```
for(var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) 
{
   var ele = mutation.addedNodes[i];
   if ( ele instanceof Element )
   {   
      ele.querySelectorAll( "*" ); //put your selector 
   }
}
```